# Reduce Code While Showing ajax loading bar for tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i use the below code to call results from a mysqli database and display them on a page with a live search function.. while loading the results it displays `<div id='ajax_request'></div>` basicaly a loading gif and on completion it hides that div and shows the div `<div id='ajax_results_table'></div>` to show the results

I'm curious to know if there is a better method out there for doing the same thing as I could have multiple requests on one page and I need each div to display loading while it's performing its own ajax request

so far I would copy the same code and change the id's for the divs

I'm completely new to ajax and would like to learn more so far this is what I have got.

#### The Html Code...

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' onkeyup='showResult(this.value)'  placeholder='Search Results'>
<div id='ajax_request'><img src='/ajax-loader.gif' class='text-center'> Fetching Data ...</div>
<div id='ajax_error'>Something went wrong with our ajax request</div>
<table id='ajax_results_table'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th> SMS ID</th>
         <th> Time Stamp</th>
         <th> Mobile Number</th>
         <th> Message</th>
         <th> Message Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody  id='ajax_results'>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

#### The Ajax Code:

```
<script>
    function showResult(str) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getjson.php?search=' + str,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            Timeout: 3000,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#ajax_request').show();
                $('#ajax_results_table').hide();
                $('#ajax_error').hide();
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                    trHTML +=
                        '<tr><td>' + value.ID +
                        '</td><td>' + value.Timestamp +
                        '</td><td>' + value.Number +
                        '</td><td>' + value.Message +
                        '</td><td>' + value.Status +
                        '</td></tr>';
                });
                $('#ajax_results').html(trHTML);
                $('#ajax_request').hide();
                $('#ajax_results_table').show();

            },
            error: function() {
                $('#ajax_request').hide();
                $('#ajax_error').show();

            }
        });

    }

    showResult('');
</script>
```

Comment: If i understand it correctly...you could have just one request and just one error indicator on the page. They will be hidden. In function `showResult` you could clone request indicator and insert it after the input. The same with error indicator in case of error. So you don't have to copy then as html elements. Is it a little in the direction of your question?

Comment: for me it looks ok, But if you have multiple request you can add css class to [div id='ajax_request'] to overlay every div seperately.. i recommend you to use angular it would not take much time to learn this, with angular js :)